# Twisting a LAN cable in the middle of another one

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, cable

Theoretically if i have 3 devices and i want to connect them through a lan cable, can i connect 2 of them with a LAN cable, then cut it in the middle and twist in a third cable. Will it work as three way lan?

Comment: No. You need a hub, switch, or router.

Comment: What will happen with the signal though? Will it just be a standard LAN cable, or will it split unpredictably and not function at all

Comment: If you do the "cut and twist" thing - you will probably stop the communication between the first two devices you connected and spoil your LAN cable

Comment: just remember, while wires are still analog, the way a computer uses them is not, so network cables are not like water in a pipe, that can be branched and merged, split and joied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you **could**, Hub Circuits can be replicated with only a [Breadboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard), but isn't a best practice (...) we always watch the [Star Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology#Star) or in advanced networks [Fully Connected Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology#Mesh) but to have all in rule you always should use the right [Networking Hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Networking_hardware) or your selected [Network Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology) will have a critical impact.

If you are doing this workaround for saving money, maybe the performance impact will be higher than what you gain.

Comment: @AudioTroubler, welcome to Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

No. That just doesn't make any sense at all. To make a sensible connection, you have to connect transmit lines to receive lines. There's no sensible three-way connection.

Answer (score 0):

The following options are available for connecting 3 devices.

**1st Option**: Use a switch / hub / router

**2nd Option**: Assuming that one of the devices you intend to connect is a desktop computer (with spare PCI slot) - install a dual Ethernet port type Network Interface Card plus drivers - now you connect to two different devices from two different ports

In case if you are using a laptop - buy a USB to Ethernet adapter and utilize the on-board Ethernet port plus your USB Ethernet port and make connections to two different devices

Answer (score 0):

No. The thing you are missing is duplex modes, and cable layouts. [Cat-5/6 cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) are 4-pair cables, meaning they have 8 individual lines within them (4+/4-). Duplex refers to how computers listen to individual cable pairs to send and recieve, and layout refers to which pair connects to which pin in the NIC on both sides.

The ISO/IEEE/TIA have developed specifications for how those wires are used. 
What you are describing is an extension of a [Cross-Over cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) layout, designed for direct NIC->NIC communication, without routers, hubs, etc.

[image]

In a most cable layouts, two pairs are used for sending, and two pairs are used for recieving. Crossover is notable because the lines for sending on one end are swapped with the lines for recieving on the other end, so the sending computers signal is sent directly into the recieving NICs recieving pins. That means there can be at most two partners sharing a piece of crossover cable.

Comment: http://s.eeweb.com/members/circuit_projects/blog/2012/01/12/the-setting-of-a-passive-ethernet-hub-1326382960.gif

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub

i think it possible, at the university we did a hub with a breadboard in lab and if works in breadboard works using only wires, i know it could be a disaster but works really.

Comment: you can definitely do a passive repeater on a breadboard. its the same idea as the old PBX switchboards in the 40's-60's, where the operator plugged this input into that output to form a connection and let Aunt Bessie call someone in the next town. The only real differance is that Aunt B would be connected to every phone in the next town, but her sister Glaydis is the only person who's phone rings.

Comment: y it is, bassicaly you are making your own hardware device, i live in southamerica i saw many (OH MY GOD how could be possible) workarounds in networking(india, malasya workarounds are more impressive).

Answer (score 0):

Direct LAN connection requires use of "Twisted cable" or "crossover cable"- that is, transmit nodes of NIC of one device need to connect to receiving nodes of another device. So it's rather impossible in currently "traditional" cabling. But that's for full-duplex. Possibly it can be done via half-duplex, but not really sure...

What you really want is going back to coaxial cabling... Maybe something along the way of G.hn (that's ITU-T communications standard)?? Was thinking for a moment about teaming-cable (in effect having three-way cable), but I think it will work with switch only.

But simple question: why at all you would want to? Used wireless switch is dirt cheap...